# why are the sets of the zeroes of the following functions isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, roots

> We have $x^2+y^2=z^2$ and $xy=z^2$. Show that the sets of points where the functions are zero are isomorphic.

I draw the graphs of the functions trying to find something and yes there is some similarity but I can't really explain it as an isomorphism. The set of the zeroes of the first function would be the pythagorean triples. I am not quite sure how this has something to do with the second. Also, the isomorphy definition is not clarified in the excercise, we need to clarify it ourselves.

Will be very happy for some help.

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of 'isomorphic'?

Comment: As I said, in the excercise it is not precised, it is lef to the reader to do it. My personal would be that there is an isomorphic function that connects the two with each other.

Comment: These are not functions.

Comment: Maybe it would help to notice that $x^2+y^2=z^2$ iff $z^2-y^2=x^2$ which can be factored.

Comment: @Somos you are right. then I have $x^2=(z-y)(z+y)$ and then say I define $u=(z-y)$ and $v=(z+y)$ what can I do then to say something about the isomorphism?

Comment: This is a classic fact in classification of quadratic forms.

Answer (score 1):

For $f$ a polynomial denote its zero set by $V(f)$. Modifying your notation you want an isomorphism

$$V(uv-w^2)\subset \mathbb{R}^3_{u,v,w} \rightarrow V(x^2+y^2-z^2)\subset \mathbb{R}^3_{x,y,z}.$$

In a comment you noticed that sending $$u\mapsto x+y, v\mapsto x-y, w \mapsto z$$ works and the inverse is easy to write down

$$x \mapsto \frac{u+v}{2}, y \mapsto \frac{u-v}{2}.$$

If you work over $\mathbb{C}$ there is a relevant piece of maths which is very beautiful. Think about the set of polynomial functions on $V(uv-w^2)$. These are polynomials in three variables, i.e., elements of $k[u,v,w]$. But two functions are the same if they differ by a multiple of $uv-w^2$. We denote the ring of functions where two are identified if they differ by a multiple of $uv-w^2$ by
$$k[u,v,w]/(uv-w^2).$$
Similarly for your other polynomial we get ring of functions $$k[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^2-z^2).$$
These rings are isomorphic - I wrote the isomorphism down above by telling you where to send $x$ and $y$ and $z$ and similarly for the inverse where to send $u,v,w$.
In fact this is a special case of the following theorem which begins algebraic geometry:

*Working over $\mathbb{C}$ the zero sets of two collections of polynomials $V(f_1(x_i),...,f_k(x_i))$ and $V(g_1(u_i),...,g_l(u_i))$ are isomorphic if and only if there is a ring isomorphism* $$k[x_i]/(f_1,...f_k) \rightarrow k[u_i]/(g_1,...,g_l).$$